# Android - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;

Tags: java, android, xml

When deploying an application on Android this issue comes up:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: JAXB is not natively supported by Android, you should use other library. For example http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException I have integrated this in android gradle and still showing same error.